# Mutt login failed in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, mutt

Can someone please help me.

I'm trying to configure mutt in Ubuntu and I'm using the following configuration in muttrc :

```
set imap_user = "test@gmail.com"
set imap_pass = "PASS"
set smtp_url = "smtp://test@smtp.gmail.com:587/"
set smtp_pass = "PASS"
set from = "test@gmail.com"
set realname = "test"
set folder = "imaps://imap.gmail.com:993"
set spoolfile = "+INBOX"
set postponed="+[Gmail]/Drafts"
set header_cache=~/.mutt/cache/headers
set message_cachedir=~/.mutt/cache/bodies
set certificate_file=~/.mutt/certificates
```

I get the following error when writing mutt in terminal:

login failed .

Any solution to this problem, please?

Comment: Well explained solution: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/172666/gmail-blocking-mutt/194247#194247

Answer (score 10):

The reason for the "Login failed" error may be the wrong password.
If you have special symbols like "$" in your password, you should use single quotes:

```
set imap_pass = 'PassWith$Symbol'
```

Double quotes didn't help.
To investigate causes of message "Login failed." you should enable debug by command:

```
mutt -d 5
```

5 mean the most verbose output) 
Output could be founded in ~/.muttdebug0 file by default.

Debug possibility shoud be enabled.
To check whether there is a parameter or not by this:
    mutt -v | grep DEBUG
Output must be like this:

```
+DEBUG
```

I have same config file and tested it with gmail. It worked successfully.

Comment: Thanks a lot you saved me from giving up mutt because I couldn't login!

Answer (score 4):

1. Ensure you have [enabled IMAP access](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?hl=en) in your Gmail account.
2. Try with the following settings:

   ```
   set from      = khalid@gmail.com
   set realname  = "khalid khalid"
   set imap_user = khalid@gmail.com
   set imap_pass = PASS
   set smtp_url  = smtp://khalid@gmail.com@smtp.gmail.com:587/
   set smtp_pass = PASS

   set folder    = imaps://imap.gmail.com/
   set spoolfile = imaps://imap.gmail.com/INBOX
   set postponed = "+[Gmail]/Drafts"

   set header_cache     =~/.mutt/cache/headers
   set message_cachedir =~/.mutt/cache/bodies
   set certificate_file =~/.mutt/certificates
   ```

Comment: I put the above setting and I enabled IMAP access in my gmail also have turn on Access for less secure apps in gmail . but stile I'm getting the error: Login Failed .

Comment: Can you include the following lines as well?: 
`set ssl_starttls = yes`
`set ssl_force_tls = yes`

Comment: I include the above two line , and again i'm getting the same error ... Is there any tutorial for mutt installation and configuration ?

Answer (score 4):

I also faced same issue. After Turning on "Less secure app access" in Google account settings, it started working.

hope it may help others.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same issue, then I turn on Less secure app access https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps then it works..

Comment: While this answer is probably helpful a little more information would be great. Maybe add some screenshots?

Answer (score 2):

I finally found a solution to this!

- I first tried what @1sloc did by removing quotes.
- I even used an [App Password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833) - Some forms stated that using an
  app password helped.
- Another attempt I did was giving access to less secure apps. Use this
  [link](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255)

Every time I debugged it with the code below

```
mutt -d 1
```

All I kept getting was Login Failed

> Then I came across this [link](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?hl=en) posted by Google. The last step is
>   what solved the problem. It told me to log in from the new device now 
>   and it finally worked!!!

It might be different for everyone but try all the above methods and see which one works for you. Also try using passwords without special characters @1sloc said. It might just solve your issue instantly

========================================================================

Comment: allowing less secure app access through gmail security settings fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

In case of accounts with 2FA (Second Factor) you can follow this simple [guide](https://www.codyhiar.com/blog/getting-mutt-setup-with-gmail-using-2-factor-auth-on-ubuntu-14-04/)

Basically, you should be able to generate 'application password' for gmail [here](https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords)

Comment: Yes, I believe that the problem of this thread comes from 2FA.